# VSE: Partial volume fade

Tags: video-sequence-editor, audio

Watching Youtube instructions on partial volume fade, in older versions of Blender, one had to add keyframes. In version 3.3, that option seems to have been removed or moved. In any case, I can't find it.

[image]

At a given frame, how do I start a volume fade from 1.0 down to 0.5, over, say, 20 frames?

Answer (score 1):

Found it. Well, found the solution.

1. Go to the video sequencer editor.
2. On the timeline move the slider (1) to the frame you want the volume to start fading.
3. Select the strip with the soundtrack (2).
4. In the properties, strip tab (3), click the little circle to the right of the volume value. It will change to a diamond (4). I believe this is a keyframe.
5. Move the slider (6) to the frame where you want the fade to stop reducing.
6. Select the strip with the soundtrack (7).
7. Enter a new value for the volume (8).
8. Click the diamond (9).

[image]

[image]

If you move the slider from left to right the volume should increase/decrease.

Here is a link to the relevant documentation: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/video_editing/edit/montage/strips/sound.html#animating-audio-track-properties

Comment: The add-on VSEQF has a feature for drawing a volume curve on top of the audio strips: https://github.com/snuq/VSEQF